# How to disable omp in Torch nn package?

Tags: lua, openmp, torch

Specifically I would like `nn.LogSoftMax` to not use omp when the size of the input tensor is small. I have a small script to test the run time.

```lua
require 'nn'
my_lsm = function(t)
    o = torch.zeros((#t)[1])
    sum = 0.0
    for i = 1,(#t)[1] do
        o[i] = torch.exp(t[i])
        sum = sum + o[i]
    end
    o = o / sum
    return torch.log(o)
end

ii=torch.randn(arg[1])
m=nn.LogSoftMax()

timer = torch.Timer()
timer:stop()
timer:reset()
timer:resume()
my_lsm(ii)
print(timer:time().real)

timer:stop()
timer:reset()
timer:resume()
m:forward(ii)
print(timer:time().real)
```

If `arg[1]` is 10, then my basic log softmax function run much faster:

```
0.00021696090698242
0.033425092697144
```

But once `arg[1]` is 10,000,000, omp really helps a lot:

```
29.561321973801 
0.11547803878784
```

So I suspect that omp overhead is very high. If my code has to call log softmax several times with small inputs (says tensor size is only 3), it will cost too much time. Is there a way to manually disable omp usage in some cases (but not always)?

Comment: How are you measuring the time?  You seem to be measuring a single invocation in which case you'll include a lot of OpenMP startup cost since it creates threads when it first goes parallel. If your real code does more than one such operation its performance will be different. (Which isn't to say that you're wrong; not using parallelism for small jobs may perform better, but it is saying that this way of measuring can be misleading).

Comment: @JimCownie, I get your point that the run times can be misleading. However, I have no control over when to create and destroy threads.

So I tested my code with additional for loop over the softmax function. The OpenMP version still takes significantly longer time in the small input case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to manually disable omp usage in some cases (but not always)?

If you really want to do that one possibility is to use [`torch.setnumthreads`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/57ff61e/utils.c#L196) and [`torch.getnumthreads`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/57ff61e/utils.c#L197) like that:

```
local nth = torch.getnumthreads()
torch.setnumthreads(1)
-- do something
torch.setnumthreads(nth)
```

So you can monkey-patch `nn.LogSoftMax` as follow:

```
nn.LogSoftMax.updateOutput = function(self, input)
  local nth = torch.getnumthreads()
  torch.setnumthreads(1)
  local out = input.nn.LogSoftMax_updateOutput(self, input)
  torch.setnumthreads(nth)
  return out
end
```